# Display related images based on text name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Instead of  "Black and Green" **text**, We are displaying "Black & Green" **images** with help of below code.

[image]

What we want is this concept should work for **all colors**, for that one solution is i need to write **manual code** for **hundreds of colors** as like below to make it work for all colors. but i think this is wrong way , may be it may impact on performance, is there any better way to handle this ?

**Script :**

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var inner = Array();
    inner = jQuery(" .product-options ul.options-list .label>label");
    for (i=0;i<inner.length;i++){
         var classN = inner[i].innerText;
          if (classN=="Black" || classN=="Green"){
               inner.eq(i).addClass(classN);
          }
     }
});
```

**Css for green :**

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label>label.Green
{ 
     font-weight: normal; 
     width: 50px; 
     height: 50px; 
     border-radius: 50%; 
     background-image: url("http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/green.png") !important; 
     background-size: cover !important; 
     display: block; 
     color: transparent; 
     padding: 0 !important; 
     font-size: 0; 
}
```

**Css for black :**

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label>label.Black
{ 
     font-weight: normal; 
     width: 50px; 
     height: 50px; 
     border-radius: 50%; 
     background-image: url("http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/black.png") !important; 
     background-size: cover !important; 
     display: block; 
     color: transparent; 
     padding: 0 !important; 
     font-size: 0; 
}
```

Comment: At least for the css you can group all the common properties under label, such as width, height, border radius, etc etc, and then change only the color assigning a new class

Comment: @DavePlug if we use css icons instead of images, can we make it work in less code  ?

Comment: Depends on what specifically you mean by “css icons”.

Comment: @CBroe please check : http://codepen.io/shahil/pen/PWWdRY

Comment: So actually just ordinary HTML elements with a background color and a border radius … What Dave said applies to that as well of course.

Comment: Please check : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJpGrj

Comment: Thanks for codepen @SandeepGarg , but i was really expecting bit different solution, but for your solution is really gave me to learn a lot....

Comment: @DavePlug Thanks a lot for your suggestion....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The js code could be simplified using an array of colors like :

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict();

jQuery(function(){
    var colors = ['Black','Green'];
    var inner = Array();

    jQuery(" .product-options ul.options-list .label>label").each(function(){
        var classN = jQuery(this).text();

        if ( jQuery.inArray(classN, colors) )
            jQuery(this).addClass(classN);
    })
});
```

Gor the CSS you could group the common attribute on `label` :

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label>label
{
    font-weight: normal; 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background-size: cover !important; 
    display: block; 
    color: transparent; 
    padding: 0 !important; 
    font-size: 0; 
}

.product-options ul.options-list .label>label.Green
{ 
    background-image: url("http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/green.png") !important;
}
.product-options ul.options-list .label>label.Black
{ 
    background-image: url("http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/black.png") !important; 
}
```

**NOTE :** You could avoid the repetition of CSS code if you use jQuery `.css()` method :

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict();

jQuery(function(){
    var colors = ['Black','Green'];
    var images = ['img_1','img_2'];
    var inner = Array();

    jQuery(" .product-options ul.options-list .label>label").each(function(i){
        var classN = jQuery(this).text();

        if ( jQuery.inArray(classN, colors) )
            jQuery(this).css('background-image','url("media/catalog/custom/'+images[i]+'")');
    })
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks , can you please check, after using `js` code, its not displaying images now.....

Comment: Remove the `{` at the end of `if ( $.inArray(classN, colors) ){`, should be just `if ( $.inArray(classN, colors) )`

Comment: Also replace the `img_1/img_2` by the real links

Comment: Yes i'm checking with you we've also to replace all the dollars `$` by `jQuery`, check my update.

Comment: the problem of `{` is back, remove it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133635/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-user5348fh8y5).

Answer (score 0):

You need to map all possible color names to a specific color code. Luckily you can use a bunch of built-in [color names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Color_keywords).

With that you could use

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label>label{ 
   font-weight: normal; 
   width: 50px; 
   height: 50px; 
   border-radius: 50%; 
   display: block; 
   color: transparent; 
   padding: 0 !important; 
   font-size: 0; 
}
```

and add the actual background color in the style-attribute of the label:

```
<label style="background-color:teal"></label>
```

Comment: i tried as you said, but not working for me, can you please update with more details.....